# Conditional expectation with respect to sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I'm working through a set of exercises, and am missing a step in the solution presented by the author. The question asks for the proof:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mathbb{P} )$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{G}$ such that $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. Let $A \geq 0$ be a random variable in $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. Prove $A > 0 \Rightarrow E \big[ A \big| \mathcal{G} \big] > 0$ almost surely.

The solution:
First, note that $$
    X = \Big\{ E\big[ A \big| \mathcal{G}  \big] \leq 0\Big\} \in \mathcal{G}. $$
Then by definition, $
    0 < E\big[ A \mathbb{1}_{X} \big] = E \big[E \big[ A \big| \mathcal{G} \big]\mathbb{1}_{X} \big] < 0
    $,
so $
    E\big[ A \mathbb{1}_{X} \big] = 0.$
Since $A>0$, $\mathbb{P}(X)=0$.

Why does this last step imply the result?

Comment: Note that $$0 < E\big[ A \mathbb{1}_{X} \big] = E \big[E \big[ A \big| \mathcal{G} \big]\mathbb{1}_{X} \big] < 0$$ should read $$0 \leqslant E\big[ A \mathbb{1}_{X} \big] = E \big[E \big[ A \big| \mathcal{G} \big]\mathbb{1}_{X} \big] \leqslant 0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That an event happens almost surely means that the probability of the event is 1. In your case this translates to
$$
E[A\mid \mathcal G] > 0 \text{ a.s.}\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad P(E[A\mid G] > 0) = 1.
$$
The latter is equivalent to 
$$
P(\underbrace{E[A\mid \mathcal G] \leq 0}_X) = 0,
$$
i.e. 
$$
P(X) = 0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad P(E[A\mid\mathcal G]>0) = 1 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad E[A\mid \mathcal G] > 0 \text{ a.s.}
$$

Comment: *palm to forehead* thank you for pointing out what should have been obvious. Still digesting these definitions and properties.